# Custom WordPress Plugin Call Ajax Return 0

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I have main file as Bellow:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: XYZ
*/

class GMS_SMS_Notifier {


public function __construct(){
    if (is_admin()){
        //JS
        add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts',array($this,'load_custom_js_scripts'));
    }
}

function load_custom_js_scripts() {
    wp_register_script( 'gms_custom', plugins_url('/assets/js/gms_custom.js', __FILE__ ),false,'1.0',true);
    wp_localize_script('gms_custom','plugin_ajax',array('ajaxurl'=>admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
    wp_enqueue_script('gms_custom');

}

function mail_send_to(){
    global $wpdb;
    echo $_POST['recordID'].'Hello';
    die();
}   
add_action('wp_ajax_mail_send_to','mail_send_to');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_mail_send_to','mail_send_to');

} // End Class GMS_SMS_Notifier

new GMS_SMS_Notifier();
```

and JS file `gms_custom.js` that looks as bellow:

```
$(".send_mail_btn").click(function(){
var recordids = $(this).attr("id");

    $.ajax({
        url: plugin_ajax.ajaxurl,
        type: 'POST',
        data: ({
        action: 'mail_send_to',
        recordID: recordids,
        }),
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
       }
   });
});
```

When I put Custom Function directly in theme's function.php it works fine, but when put it on plugin file instead it will not work. What am I doing wrong and what do I need to change to make it work from plugin as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These add_action calls:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_mail_send_to','mail_send_to');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_mail_send_to','mail_send_to');
```

need to be inside your class's constructor or they won't execute. The 0 is WordPress's default response when it doesn't have an AJAX handler defined for an action.

To address the comment below, note that when a function is inside a class (i.e. it becomes a *method*) you have a refer to it differently when you call functions like add_action. The most common & compatible way to refer to a method is to use an array with two elements: the name of the class, and the name of the method. For example:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_mail_send_to',array('GMS_SMS_Notifier', 'mail_send_to'));
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_mail_send_to',array('GMS_SMS_Notifier', 'mail_send_to'));
```

The [PHP docs for *callables*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) cover all the different ways you can refer to a function or method when passing one to a function.

Comment: your right Thanks: In my case add_action('wp_ajax_mail_send_to', array($this,'mail_send_to' ));

Answer (score 0):

I think you have do not have "}" in the end of the function before adding action.

```
function mail_send_to(){
    global $wpdb;
    echo $_POST['recordID'].'Hello';
    die();
}
```

Comment: thank you for response me. but actual code that already closing brackets.I have updated code